# Consuming API Endpoints in Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am building an Android app in Kotlin and I am consuming a FastAPI (Python) API. The response on success and error is different. Most of the times it is JSON, but there are also cases when text or binary is returned.

I am using Retrofit and coroutines for handling requests. I am quite new in Android development, and I need some help on how to handle responses with different structures in success and error.

A success response for the login endpoint is

```
` return {
"access_token": token, 
"token_type": "bearer"
}`
```

and the error response for the same endpoint is the FastAPI one

```
`{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "string"
      ],
      "msg": "string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}`
```

Comment: Can you provide some samples of the error or success return  ??

Comment: I have edited the post to include an example of success and error response.